# Keeping offset indentation of YAML file using python ruamel-yaml

Tags: python, yaml, ruamel.yaml

I'm trying to use ruamel-yaml to achieve the following I have a YAML file with a set of variables like so (please note the fact that all of the keys start with an indentation of 6):

```yml
      app:
        version: 'latest'
        env: 'test'

      #auth
      auth_endpoint: 'http://localhost/login'
      auth_token: 23NSDQD94NFDFKF0SQS
```

My idea is to provide the user a python script that will generate the config files but with overridden values, so basically I will parse the arguments, load the YAML file change the values and dump the YAML file with the updated values and this all works fine, except when the file gets dumped the indentation of 6 is lost, except for the comments, (see code below)

```yml
app:
  version: 'latest'
  env: 'test'

      #auth
auth_endpoint: 'http://localhost/login'
auth_token: 23NSDQD94NFDFKF0SQS
```

Now this indentation is important since this file will then be parsed and merged to a larger YAML file

```python
def update_yaml(file):
  yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
  yaml.indent(mapping=6)
  config_yaml = yaml.load(file)
  # value changing code ommited for readability
  with open(os.path.join(sys.path[0], "config.yml"), 'w') as file:
    yaml.dump(config_yml, file)
```

I've tried a few things with the indent method to no avail, any idea how I can keep this original indentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, it is not true that all of your keys have an indentation of 6, as
the keys `version` and `env`, that are part of the mapping that is value for the
root level key `app`, **are only indented two positions**.

`ruamel.yaml` will force your output to be consistent with regards to indentation. All mappings will be indented the same, and all sequences as well (although mappings and sequences can differ). Since the output that you want is
not consistent, you'll need to do some post processing:

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

yaml_str = """\
      app:
        version: 'latest'
        env: 'test'

      #auth
      auth_endpoint: 'http://localhost/login'
      auth_token: 23NSDQD94NFDFKF0SQS
"""

class PushRootLeft:
    def __init__(self, positions=42):
        self.positions = positions

    def __call__(self, s):
        result = []
        for line in s.splitlines(True):
            sline = line.strip()
            if not sline or sline[0] == '#':
                result.append(line)
            else:
                result.append(' ' * self.positions + line)
        return ''.join(result)

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.indent(mapping=2) # not necessary, this is the default
yaml.preserve_quotes = True

data = yaml.load(yaml_str)
print('123456780') # just to better see the alignment of the actual YAML output
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout, transform=PushRootLeft(6))
```

which gives:

```
123456780
      app:
        version: 'latest'
        env: 'test'

      #auth
      auth_endpoint: 'http://localhost/login'
      auth_token: 23NSDQD94NFDFKF0SQS
```

You should set `.preserve_quotes` as some (broken) parser don't like the colon in your URL unquoted,
the interpret that as value indicator, even though it is not followed by a space.

That you have to do something special for comments is because on round-trip it knows in which column it originally appeared and will try to get restored there (unless some value changes pushes it right).

The [recommended extension for YAML files has been `.yaml`](https://yaml.org/faq)  since September 2006.

Comment: It is an unfortunate limitation that the indentation is not preserved for a "round-trip" loader. Is this something you are likely to fix, or is the round-trip part only referring to comments?

Comment: I don't plan on making a per collection-item indentation preservation beyond the seperate settings for mappings and sequences (already a 100% improvement over other libraries). Consistency in layout is IMO more important. I might do an analysis of the layout during loading and make that queriable afterwards on the YAML instance. Something like that would allow you to set the indent for mappings resp. sequences to the most commonly occuring values (instead of the first value encountered as the routine in `ruamel/yaml/util.py` now does.

Comment: Thanks for the context. Personally I disagree that consistency in indentation trumps the full round-trip. It would be easy to normalise the indentation once loaded (this could even be the default behaviour) if that is desired, but the losing information about the indentation is really unfortunate when you just want to inject something new into an existing YAML file without destroying the original formatting.

Comment: I see your point, but I don't think it is feasable to implement indent per collection, per item spaces after mapping/sequence delimeter etc

Comment: Yes, I can completely understand that. Thank you again for your input all the same.